# Docker commit doesn't save the changed state of my container

Tags: docker

I am a newbie about Docker. But I have looked many guides of that. I am configuring a container that it is running in a base image of jenkins with blue-ocean plugin. I run this one using docker run command and I configured my proxy information and added another plugin, k8s plugin through Jenkins Manage Plugin UI. Then I stop this container and I commit this container to save this state that has the k8s plugin and proxy information that I set already. But I run new docker image that I have made with docker commit command I can't see any proxy information and k8s plugin. It is same image that I started. Is there something I miss?

Comment: Did you mapping some volume?

Comment: @German no I didn't. you mean that I need to mount some volumes to save  those states??

Comment: You dont need map a volume. I did ask because the commit dont save the information inside of volume.

Comment: Can you post the procedure you use to create the images and run the new container?

Comment: @German ok I will I am out of office I will add the procedure. Anyway how can I save the information in the volume through commit?

Comment: Just can not add information in the image if it is in a volume. Should work as you are doing.

Comment: @German thanks for your help. I decided that I will declare another JENKINS_HOME in the container. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JENKINS_HOME is [set to be a volume in the default Jenkins Docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/6a74b7da7ef84a36679fdb39a6f94e1d75b4054f/Dockerfile#L21) (which I'm assuming you're using). Volumes live outside of the Docker container layered filesystem. This means that any changes in those folders will not be persisted in subsequent image commits.

Comment: thanks for your answer.     so If I delete the volume in the dockerfile, can I save the changes through commit? and is there any way to delete this volume statement in another file that I import this using FROM statement?

Comment: You could modify the Dockerfile and rebuild your own base. Or a quicker way would be to just pass a new $JENKINS_HOME value into the container at runtime. This is a pretty crappy UX imo but it looks like a PR to change this behaviour was rejected - https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/pull/55.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer with the link. I won't pull request but I will use it only in my local. thanks again.